# How to populate TableView with data from a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, multidimensional-array, tableview

I've got an array called `details` in the class `Table`. I wish to have the `TableView` to be populated with the contents from the array. However, I'm not sure to how it's done. I tried looking for a similar issue, but couldn't find a solution. Apologies if the question is already answered. The `Table` class is as follows(note, I've removed the `import` statements for simplicity).

```
public class Table extends Application
{
    private static String details[][] = new String[2][2] ;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        initialize() ;

        Application.launch(args) ;
    }

    private static void initialize()
    {
        details[0][0] = "Peter" ;
        details[0][1] = "Jones" ;

        details[1][0] = "Marcus" ;
        details[1][1] = "Anthony" ;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window)
    {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>() ;

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name") ;
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName")) ;
        firstNameColumn.setPrefWidth(200) ;

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name") ;
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName")) ;
        lastNameColumn.setPrefWidth(200) ;

        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameColumn, lastNameColumn) ;
        
        /* Not so sure to what goes in here */

        VBox vbox = new VBox(table) ;
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10)) ;
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER) ;

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 425, 300) ;

        window.setScene(scene) ;
        window.show() ;
    }

    private ObservableList<Person> loadData(int index)
    {
        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList() ;

        /* Not so sure to what goes in here */

        return data ;
    }
}
```

The custom class, `Person`, that defines the objects that's displayed in the table is :

```
public class Person
{
    private String firstName, lastName ;

    public TableContent(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName ;
        this.lastName = lastName ;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName ;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName ;
    }
}
```

Comment: So which is it? you want to populate the TableView with the object Person?  Or with the String matrix details?

Comment: @b3tuning The TableView with the object Person

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an ArrayList of the Person objects then you can do the following:

```
ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(personArrayList);
```

Then you have an ObservableList with your Person objects and can set the data to the table like so:

```
table.setItems(data);
```

data being the ObservableList.